# UK transit visa fee refund

Tags: uk, transit-visas, applications, refunds

I applied for a UK visa online with all my details and submitted the application. Also paid the application fee online.

The next day I realized that I made a few errors in my application. I did not want to get a rejection because of those small mistakes (basically didn't want to take chances). So I cancelled my application online.

I received an email from UK visa stating that "you will receive an email when a decision will be made".
When will i receive the refund?

Answer (score 4):

If you’re eligible for a refund, it will be automatically paid into the bank account you used to pay your fees when you applied.

It can take up to 28 days to get your refund.

Source: [Cancel your visa, immigration or citizenship application](https://www.gov.uk/cancel-visa)